# ESS poly-R issue

Tags: ess, polymode

I am trying to setup ESS with polymode and poly-markdown

I have the following in my `myinit.org` file which becomes
compiled into `init.el`

```
;; https://polymode.github.io/installation/
     (use-package poly-markdown
       :ensure t)

;; https://github.com/vspinu/polymode
(use-package polymode
       :diminish (poly-org-mode
              poly-markdown-mode
              poly-noweb+r-mode
              poly-noweb+r-mode
              poly-markdown+r-mode
              poly-rapport-mode
              poly-html+r-mode
              poly-brew+r-mode
              poly-r+c++-mode
              poly-c++r-mode)
       :init
       (require 'poly-R)
       (require 'poly-markdown)
       :config
       (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.md$" . poly-markdown-mode))
       (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Rmd$" . poly-markdown+r-mode))
       (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Rcpp$" . poly-r+c++-mode))
       (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.cppR$" . poly-c++r-mode))
       )
```

When restarting and loading my emacs I keep getting the error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-missing "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "poly-R")
  require(poly-R)
  (progn (require 'poly-R) (require 'poly-markdown))
  (condition-case err (progn (require 'poly-R) (require 'poly-markdown)) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning73 :init err)))
  (progn (condition-case err (progn (require 'poly-R) (require 'poly-markdown)) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning73 :init err))) (if (not (require 'polymode nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" 'polymode) :error) (condition-case err (progn (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.md$" . poly-markdown-mode)) (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Rmd$" . poly-markdown+r-mode))
```

There is more to the error message, but not sure why the issue is occurring with `poly-R`.

Could anyone please assist to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you installed the package `poly-R`?

Comment: Ah, adding in ` (use-package poly-R
   :ensure t)` worked! I thought it was being installed in the above statement but did not realize that I had to install it separately like the `polymarkdown` package. Thanks for your help. If you put this as an answer I can mark it correct as it helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing `polymode` doesn't automatically install all the related modes that it uses to support different languages. The error message you see, "No such file or directory" "poly-R")" is a clue that the `poly-R` package doesn't exist on your system, so you need to install is before you can `require` it.

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate the details here as a newbie into the emacs world